# Nodejs on Amazon ec2 server, cannot handle POST request with multipart/form-data

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, multipart, form-data, enctype

Really need help.

Nodejs cannot receive POST request when enctype="multipart/form-data", browser just hangs.. no response, nothing happens and then timeout (later files could be found in specified folder on server with name of hash string). The code is tested locally, where it works fine.

**Request info (from Google Chrome Network Tab)**

> Headers: Content-Type:multipart/form-data;
>
> Payload: Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="1_leaf_music.png"
>
> Responce: empty

POST requests with other enctype "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" works fine, as it should, hangs only when "multipart/form-data".

Installed on Amazon ec2 virtual server, everything else works fine.

> Example > hangs on callback > app.post('/form-file', ... > console.log never trace

app.js:

```
var http    = require('http');
var express     = require('express');
var path    = require('path');
var app     = express();

app.configure(function(){
    app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
    app.set('view engine', 'jade');
    app.use(express.favicon());
    app.use(express.bodyParser({uploadDir:__dirname + '/public/uploads'}));
    app.use(express.methodOverride());
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
});

app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
    console.log('get:/');
    res.render('index', { title: 'Upload a single file (using Express BodyParser()) ' })
});

app.post('/form-file', function(req, res, next)  {
    console.log("multipart/form-data recived... file recived: ",req.files.file.name);
    res.send("multipart/form-data recived... file recived: " + req.files.file.name);
});

app.post('/form-text', function(req, res, next)  {
    console.log("application/x-www-form-urlencoded: txt: ",req.body.txt);
    res.send("application/x-www-form-urlencoded... txt: " + req.body.txt);
});

var port = 8001;
http.createServer(app).listen(port, function() {
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + port);
});
```

view:

```
<code>
form(method="post", name="f", action="/form-file", enctype="multipart/form-data")
  fieldset
    legend Upload a File
    input(type="file", name="file")
  div.actions
    button.btn.primary(type="submit") Upload
    button.btn.cancel(type="button") Cancel
</code>
```

the same code life on amazon server:
http://node.form.co.il:8001/

**Update:**
The problem is in module bodyParser. If it is removed, node will fire response as expected.

Comment: Are your filesystem permissions set correctly? Can the `node` process write to the upload directory?

Comment: Had a similar issue when using forever... https://github.com/nodejitsu/forever , to keep the server running. Is that a probable cause?

Comment: node can create files, read and write, tested

Comment: somehow got error, instead of just hanging events.js:69
       throw arguments[1]; // Unhandled 'error' event
                      ^
Error: Invalid data
   at WriteStream._write (fs.js:1618:31)
   at WriteStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:155:8)
   at WriteStream.Writable.end (_stream_writable.js:278:10)

Comment: removing bodyParser did the trick!